# CoreData - NSFetchRequest AND Filter On Child Relationship Entities

Tags: iphone, core-data

Ok, say I have many entities of type "Office" and it has a relationship called "employees" which is a to-many relationship containing "Employee" objects. "Employee" has an attribute called "lastName".

Given that, I need to do a fetch that returns an array of Office objects which have > 0 employees but in the returned Offices, the Employee objects inside the employees relationship has been filtered down to include only Employee objects where the lastName equals "Smith".

I could easily just get all the Office objects and then iterate through them and remove all the employees whose name doesn't match Smith however that would delete those objects in the store.

I'm assuming SUBQUERY is required here but I can't seem to get it filtering correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: __I can't seem to get it filtering correctly__, show us some code?

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible. A fetch request returns an array of objects, and accessing their relationships gives the related objects are they are currently defined in the managed object context. A filter can restrict *which objects* the fetch request returns, but not the *properties* of the returned objects.

Comment: Yes Martin R, that's the conclusion I've come to. I think I'm going to have to grab all the employees, filter them and store them in a temporary place without touching the original set of all the employees. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

You want a `SUBQUERY` in your predicate.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(employees, lastName, lastName LIKE[cd] %@).@count > 0", @"Smith"]
```

This performs a subquery on each `employees` relationship, testing lastName for the provided string, and counting that there is at least one such employee.